# Sharepoint 2013 public view of MySite and WebPartZones in private

Tags: 2013, my-site

Anybody know how to configure mysite so that when another user browse to my site, he/she only views some webparts? Is it possible that the user moves the webparts in other webpart zones within MySite? How?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to show only selected web-parts for users is to use audience feature of SharePoint. And allowing user to move webpart is not allowed as it is your site and not allowed.